# How to change Unity Android project name?

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am using Unity to create augmented reality application. This app plays a videoplayback when an image target is detected.

In my android app I want to create 3 buttons, where each button leads to the AR camera. When the target is detected, the played video should differ depending on which button is clicked (i.e. play the same video with different languages).

For this issue I have created 3 unity projects and assigned different package name to each one.

But when I try to import projects to eclipse, I couldn't import more than one project, because they all have the same project name `(UnityPlayerNativeActivity)`.

How can I change the name of the Unity Projects, or is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: You have to import them one at a time, each time you import a project change it's name during import. That should work

Comment: I cannot change the project name anywhere, when I try to import the second project, it doesn't because it has the same name as the previous (UnityNativePlayerActivity) @AhmedAbidi

Comment: For example in this interface you can change the name of the imported project by double clicking the "New project Name" [see example](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/images/eclipse_import_play_lib.png)